# Use Custom Type to Create in Memory Array - PLS-00306 Wrong Number of Arguments

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to create an in memory array of all the tables which have spatial metadata and a spatial index.

*I have run into an error,

> PLS-00306 Wrong Number of Arguments

, in the code below on the line:**

```
v_idx_info_arr(v_array_counter) := 
                 idx_info_arr('THE_TABLE','THE_OWNER','THE_INDEX_NAME');
```

**Why is this the wrong number of arguments when the type "index_info" has 3 fields of type varchar2(100)?**

I do plan to change the code from that^ to `idx_info_arr(rec.index_name, rec.table_owner, rec.table_name);` but for testing I've left it with just hard coded strings.

I also am not sure about how the custom types and arrays work here in PL/SQL because I've been piecing it together from documentation and stack overflow questions. Any corrections on those declarations and usage is welcome.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE index_info IS RECORD(
        table_name varchar2(100),
        table_owner varchar2(100),
        index_name varchar2(100)
    );

    CURSOR all_geom_tables IS
    SELECT gt.owner, gt.table_name, gt.column_name, gt.srid
        FROM all_sdo_geom_metadata gt
        WHERE SRID = 8311            
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;

    type idx_info_arr is table of index_info;
    array v_idx_info_arr := idx_info_arr();
    v_array_counter integer := 0;

    v_table_geom sdo_geometry;
    v_spt_index varchar2(100);
    v_view_count integer;
    v_index_count integer;
BEGIN 
-- Start Loop Through all tables in database
    FOR db_table IN all_geom_tables LOOP  
        -- Loop through all tables which have a spatial index
        FOR rec IN (select table_name, table_owner, index_name 
   from ALL_SDO_INDEX_INFO WHERE 
 TABLE_OWNER = db_table.owner
    AND TABLE_NAME = db_table.table_name) LOOP                    
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Index name is: ' || rec.index_name);                    
            -- record the index here
      v_idx_info_arr(v_array_counter) := idx_info_arr('THE_TABLE','THE_OWNER','THE_INDEX_NAME');            
            v_idx_info_arr.extend();
            v_array_counter := v_array_counter + 1;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For versions below Oracle 18c, You cannot assign all the record element at once. They must be assigned individually. Also, `v_idx_info_arr.extend` is required before the loop as even after initialisation without specifying elements, the collection would still be  zero sized.

Code for versions upto Oracle 12.2

```
DECLARE
     TYPE index_info IS RECORD ( table_name        VARCHAR2(100),
     table_owner       VARCHAR2(100),
     index_name        VARCHAR2(100) );
     TYPE idx_info_arr IS
          TABLE OF index_info;
     v_idx_info_arr    idx_info_arr := idx_info_arr ();
     v_array_counter   INTEGER := 1;

BEGIN
     v_idx_info_arr.extend;
     FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
          v_idx_info_arr(v_array_counter).table_name := 'THE_TABLE';
          v_idx_info_arr(v_array_counter).table_owner := 'THE_OWNER';
          v_idx_info_arr(v_array_counter).index_name := 'THE_INDEX_NAME';
          v_idx_info_arr.extend ();
          v_array_counter := v_array_counter + 1;
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Oracle 18c introduced [**Qualified expressions**](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2018/03/qualified-expressions-aka-constructor.html) which lets you to do so.

```
v_idx_info_arr(v_array_counter)  := 
                  index_info('THE_TABLE','THE_OWNER','THE_INDEX_NAME');
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=44f7c02017b58dd97f091d23accc884b) for 18c

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, that solved my problem and made my code a lot better